# Integrating google checkout in Android?

Tags: android, google-checkout

Is there any way we can integrate Google Checkout in Android?

I am able to post the order request and in response I get the checkout redirect url where the user is redirected. But then how to proceed with it. How will the android application come to know when the payment is done.

The redirect url is called in Webview and then there is no connection between the mobile app and google checkout. How can the mobile application get the response from Google checkout?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for an in-app purchase user experience, Google Checkout may not be the best choice, as there is no automatic re-direct for the buyer after the Google Checkout transaction finishes. You may want to consider Google In-App Payments API which provides the notification callback you are looking for. Please note that this API is for web-based apps only:

http://code.google.com/apis/inapppayments/

For Android Market In-app Billing, please see:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to setup a server than can handle notifications and check for the charged/charging flag. IN your mobile app, probably you can poll for the status change to your server.